# Variable Search, Cascading Combo Boxes

Tags: ms-access

I'm running into an issue where I have a group of combo boxes that I have set to update based upon the previous boxes.  It is functional to this point.

I have 12 (yes 12) different search criteria that a user can use to locate the item they are looking for.  Only 1 of those items is required.  The issue is that in some cases, they only have certain criteria that the customer has given us.  My boxes are:

```
MaterialType (Required field.  We always will have this)
Durometer
Tensile
Elongation
C-Tear
SG
Modulus-100
Modulus-200
Modulus-300
TempRange
BrittlePt
CureType
```

All of the subsequent fields are items that we may have.  In many cases, the customer only gives 2 or 3 of the above.

How can I set this up so that the user can select the MaterialType, then say Durometer and SG one day; the MaterialType and TempRange and BrittlePt the next?

At this point, I've only tried a few different queries.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the issue of course here is that we do not actually have cascading combo boxes.

Cascading combo boxes means that say I select a city, and then the 2nd combo box to select a hotel would be based on, and choices limited based on what city I selected in the first combo box. Hence the term "cascade", since the choice(s) in that second combo box (say select Hotel) is based on or "cascaded" from the previous combo box choices.

In your example, we not doing any kind of cascading, but simple have a bunch of choices on some form, and all of them are optional to the user in what is to be used for the filter.

Of course, recalling high school math when we took combinations, permutations and probability?

Well, with just 12 choices, that means we could in theory have 479,001,600 different queries to deal with every possible combination.

However, there is a simple workaround, and it works for 5, or 30 different filter choices. The trick is to "combine" each entry by the user, and simply ignore any control/choice left blank.

So, any drop down, or any text box, or check box, or whatever? If they are blank, we simply ignore (means "all" in effect for that choice).

So, say this filter:

[image]

So, in above, all of the text boxes, check boxes, and combo box filter options are optional (not used = all/no criteria).

So, the code (design pattern) looks like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strWhere    As String
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels "
    
    ' first name
    If sFirstName <> "" Then
        strWhere = "(FirstName like '" & sFirstName & "*' ) "
    End If
    
    
    ' last name
    If sLastName <> "" Then
    
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
            
        strWhere = strWhere & "(LastName like '" & sLastName & "*' ) "
       
    End If
    
    ' combo box for city
    
    If cboCity <> "" Then
       If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
       
       strWhere = strWhere & "(City = '" & cboCity & "') "
    End If
    
    ' include only active hotels check box
    If ChkActive Then
       If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
       
       strWhere = strWhere & "(Active = true)"
    End If
    
    ' Hotel name
    If txtHotelName <> "" Then
       If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
       
       strWhere = strWhere & "(HotelName like '" & txtHotelName & "*') "
    
    End If
    
    ' Must have description check box
    If chkDescription Then
       If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
       
       strWhere = strWhere & "(Description is not null)"
    
    End If
    
    
    ' we now have valid filter.
    '
    ' docmd.OpenReport "rptHotels", acviewPreview,,strWhere
    
    
    If strWhere <> "" Then
       strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY HotelName"
    
    
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
    
    

End Sub
```

So, if you look at above, we can with great ease add more conditions. And we just use that same pattern over and over.

Say we added a check box for no GST taxes hotels.

Well, we drop in a check box, and simply add the new criteria:

So, say like this:

```
    ' No GST tax hotels
    If chkDescription Then
       If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
       
       strWhere = strWhere & "(NoGSTTtax = false)"
    
    End If
```

And it does not matter if we have 4 or 40 previous conditions, we again simple "append/add" to the existing filter for as many criteria as we desire.

As above shows, the resulting filter can be used in some SQL query, or the filter can be used to launch/open a report or form using the openForm "where clause" which is a standard SQL where clause.
And thus, the above approach avoids the need for different queries and criteria. The choices grow at a factorial rate. Hence, with above simple example of 6 choices? Well, then 6! = 720 possible combinations.

So, this simple design choice of assuming empty controls are to be ignored, and appending only controls with a choice allows one to avoid the factorial growth in the number of SQL queries required.

Comment: "***group of combo boxes that I have set to update based upon the previous boxes***" may or may not be "cascading" - not clear. However, cascading not the issue - dynamic filtering of records is. Certainly a detailed answer and expansion on Allen Browne tutorial referenced in earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks kindly. My approach is really not much different than Allen's approach (I don't chop off the last "AND", and this costs 1 extra line of code per criteria,  but I always preferred my approach since then with one or no criteria I don't have that chopping issue). Really either way is fine choice - could flip a coin on this....